# Bash delimit string without IFS

Tags: bash, shell

I have an email like `first.last@company.com`
and the output should be `first_last`

I tried delimiting on `@` first and then replaced `.` with `_` 
Is there an easier single line way to do it without using IFS?

Comment: Can you show how you did it **with** IFS?

Comment: The answer is yes.
(but maybe you'd like to actually share the command you tried...?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter expansion:

```
#! /bin/bash
email=first.last@company.com
name=${email%@*}   # Remove everything after the last @.
name=${name//./_}  # Replace all dots by underscores.
echo "$name"
```

Comment: Is it possible to compress this into a single line without using any extra variable? I have this command `gcloud auth list --format="value(account)"` which outputs an email

Comment: You can use an external command like `sed`, but it would be much slower.